# Javascript - How to clear setInterval inside a callback using a onClick event listener that is not in the same scope

Tags: javascript, timer, promise, setinterval, intervals

#### I want to accomplish the following:

- <s>Send 10 fetch requests *sequentially* and measure response time for each request (in millisec)</s>
- <s>For each request push response time to an array</s>
- On click of a *start* button - starts the plotting of points with a predefined function: `drawChart(data)` . The points should be added in 1 second intervals.
- On click of a *stop* button - stop the plotting.

---

I successfully make the graph plot at 1 second intervals..but what I can't wrap my mind about is how to `clearInterval` in the window context when the `setInterval` is defined within a callback. The `onclick` for the stop button will not have scope of the `setInterval`.

#### onLoad event listener:

```
window.onload = async function () {
   drawChart([]);
   const data = await fetchData(15);
   document.getElementById("start").onclick = () => plotData(data);

   // I want to be able to clearInterval on click of Stop button... but its not working...
   document.getElementById("stop").onclick = clearInterval(plotData);  
};
```

#### plot / fetch function:

```
const plotData = (data) => {
  let i = 0;
  // How do i clear this interval outside of this function?
  const interval = setInterval( () => {
    i++;
    if (i === data.length) { clearInterval(interval); }
    let newData = data.slice(0,i);
    drawChart(newData); 
    console.log('draw');
  }, 1000);
}

const fetchData = async (times) => {
  let url = `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-1295/lounging-dog.jpg`;
  const data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    start = (new Date()).getTime();
    await fetch(url)
      .then( res => {
        end = (new Date()).getTime();
        console.log('times', i+1);
        console.log('response milisec', end - start);            
        data.push({ xVal: i+1, yVal: end-start}); 
      })
      .catch( e => console.log(e));   
  }
  return data;
};
```

You can also see my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/alchuang/pen/wvwXrER) for more information.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a scope issue. You need to define `interval` outside of both functions. Then it's in the parent scope of the functions and therefore they can both access it. The way you do it now only allows access to `interval` from within `plotData`.
Also, it'd need to be a `let` or `var` since it would get set every time you click the relevant button to start it and `const`s don't allow reassignment

Comment: Hi! thanks for answering so quickly.. I tried your approach in my Codepen https://codepen.io/alchuang/pen/wvwXrER but still not working.. also, it makes it that when I click on the button multiple times. setInterval gets re-triggered.. is there anyway to prevent this? Can you take a look real quickly and try clicking the button if you have time? Appreciate it

Comment: Nvm- i resolved the issue with the clicking multiple times by wrapping the setInterval in a if condition. However, stop button still not working though with interval defined globally

Comment: Not sure what you'd expect to happen when clicking stop. For me it deletes the chart, but that may be because you call drawChart with an empty array as input.

Comment: Change `clearInterval(plotData)` to `clearInterval(interval)`.

Comment: Avoid the global namespace by moving both worker functions, `fetchData` and `plotData`, and the variable `interval` into the `window.onload` function.